# How to print a function in the main function

Tags: python, concatenation, program-entry-point

```
import math
```

return def is_valid(filing_status, income):

```
  """Function determines whether the input is valid. If valid, it returns 'True'. The filing status must come from the list of options given and the income must be an integer greater than 0. If these qualifications are not met, the function will return 'False'.""" 

   x = filing_status
   y = income
   def setup(x, y):
   if x in ('single', 'married filing jointly', 'married filing separately', 'widow', 'head of household') and y >= 0:
    print "True"
   else:
    print "False"
   setup(x, y)

return def tax(filing_status, income):

"""Fuction displays the value of taxes that different groups of people are required to pay based on their income."""

  f = filing_status
  i = income
  def calculation(f, i):
  if f in ('single') and int(0 < i <= 9275):
     print int(i*0.100)
  elif 9276 <= i <= 37650:
     print int((i-9276.00)*0.15 + 9275.*0.1)
  elif 37651 <= i <= 91150:
     print int((i-37651)*0.25 + 28375*0.15 + 9275*0.1)
  elif 91151 <= i <= 190150:
     print int((i-91151)*0.28 + 53500*0.25 + 28375*0.15 + 9275*0.1)
  elif 190151 <= i <= 413350:
     print int((i-190151)*0.33 + 99000*0.28 + 53500*0.25 + 28375*0.15 + 9275*0.1)
  elif 413351 <= i <= 415050:
     print int((i-413351)*0.35 + 223200*0.33 + 99000*0.28 + 53500*0.25 + 28375*0.15 + 9275*0.1)
  elif i >= 415051:
     print int((i-415051)*0.396 + 1700*0.35 + 223200*0.33 + 99000*0.28 + 53500*0.25 + 28375*0.15 + 9275*0.1)
  calculation(f,i)

 return def tax(filing_status,income):
 c = filing_status
 d = income
   def calculation(c,d):
   if c in ('widow','married filing jointly') and 0 < d <= 18550:
     print int(d*0.1)
   elif 18551 <= d <= 75300:
     print int((d-18551)*0.15 + 18550*0.1)
   elif 75301 <= d <= 151900:
     print int((d-75301)*0.25 + 56750*0.15 + 18550*0.1)
   elif 151901 <= d <= 231450:
     print int((d-151901)*0.28 + 76600*0.25 + 56750*0.15 + 18550*0.1)
   elif 231451 <= d <= 413350:
     print int((d-231451)*0.33 + 79550*0.28 +76600*0.25 + 56750*0.15 + 18550*0.1)
   elif 413351 <= d <= 466950:
     print int((d-413351)*0.35 + 181900*0.33 + 79550*0.28 +76600*0.25 + 56750*0.15 + 18550*0.1)
   elif d >= 466951:
     print int((d-466951)*0.396 + 53600*0.35 + 181900*0.33 + 79550*0.28 +76600*0.25 + 56750*0.15 + 18550*0.1)
  calculation(c,d)

return def tax(filing_status,income):
  g = filing_status
  h = income
  def calculation(g,h):
    if g in ('married filing separately') and 0 < h <= 9275:
       print int(h*0.1)
    elif 9276 <= h <= 37650:
       print int((h-9276)*0.15 + 9275*0.1)
    elif 37651 <= h <= 75950:
       print int((h-37651)*0.25 + 28375*0.15 + 9275*0.1)
    elif 75951 <= h <= 115725:
       print int((h-75951)*0.28 + 38300*0.25 + 28375*0.15 + 9275*0.1)
    elif 115726 <= h <= 206675:
       print int((h-115726)*0.33 + 39775*0.28 +38300*0.25 + 28375*0.15 + 9275*0.1)
    elif 206676 <= h <= 233475:
       print int((h-206676)*0.35 + 90950*0.33 + 39775*0.28 +38300*0.25 + 28375*0.15 + 9275*0.1)
    elif h >= 233476:
       print int((h-233476)*0.396 + 26800*0.35 + 90950*0.33 + 39775*0.28 +38300*0.25 + 28375*0.15 + 9275*0.1)

    calculation(g,h)

return def tax(filing_status,income):
    m = filing_status
    n = income
    def calculation(m,n):
       if m in ('head of household') and 0 < n <= 13250:
          print int(n*0.1)
       elif 13251 <= n <= 50400:
          print int((n-13251)*0.15 + 13250*0.1)
       elif 50401 <= n <= 130150:
          print int((n-50401)*0.25 + 37150*0.15 + 13250*0.1)
       elif 130151 <= n <= 210800:
          print int((n-130151)*0.28 + 79750*0.25 + 37150*0.15 + 13250*0.1)
       elif 210801 <= n <= 413350:
          print int((n-210801)*0.33 + 80649*0.28 +79750*0.25 + 37150*0.15 + 13250*0.1)
       elif 413351 <= n <= 441000:
          print int((n-413351)*0.35 + 202550*0.33 + 80649*0.28 +79750*0.25 + 37150*0.15 + 13250*0.1)
       elif n >= 441001:
          print int((n-441001)*0.396 + 27649*0.35 + 202550*0.33 + 80649*0.28 +79750*0.25 + 37150*0.15 + 13250*0.1)

      calculation(m,n)

return def percent_of_income(tax, income):
   """Function calculates the percent of income that goes to taxes."""

    t = tax
    s = income
    def calc_percent (t, s):
       print (t/s)*100
    calc_percent(t, s)

return def main(filing_status,income):
  """Function brings the previous functions together to describe taxes and the percent of income of individuals based on their filing statuses"""

  w = filing_status
  o = income
  v = tax(filing_status, income)
  if w not in ('single', 'married filing jointly', 'married filing separately', 'widow', 'head of household'): 
     print "Invalid input. Filing status must be 'single', 'married filing jointly', 'married filing separately', 'widow', or 'head of household'. Income must be greater than or equal to zero."
  if o < 0: 
     print "Income must be greater than or equal to zero." 
  else:
     return ('Tax: $', str(v))
     return ('Tax as % of income: $', str(percent_of_income(tax, income)) + '%')
```

Trying to print the tax and percent of income functions in the main. How do I reference this? I am not sure if the variables in the percent of income are  documented correctly, and everytime i try to run the function, it won't print the tax value inside of the string "Tax;". I also tried concatenating that.

Comment: I can't find out why this won't print the functions "tax" and "percent of income" that i defined above this main function

Comment: when I print it, it said main('single',30000)
3837
=> ('Tax: $', 'None')

Comment: You have two `return` statements in your `else` clause. The second will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I need a little more info to help you out, but I'll try.

It looks like with this function that you are only printing if the first or second ifs are executed. If they are not, you are executing the else, which only returns a tuple without printing. Also, the second return will not be executed. Once a return is executed, the function ends.

Comment: After looking at the other comments I think your issue is that you are trying to return twice. Like I said above, once a return is executed, the function ends execution. This means that your second return is never executed. You can combine the two returns however. Try: 

    return ("Tax: $\nTax as % of income: $", str(v), str(percent_of_income(tax, income)) + "%")

Comment: I posted the rest of the code so that you can see. Thank you so much! I will try what you said real quick.

Comment: main('single',40000)
5337
=> ('Tax: $', 'None')

Comment: ^ this is what happens when I put in  
if o < 0: 
    print "Income must be greater than or equal to zero." 
  else:
    return ('Tax: $', str(v))

Comment: If o < 0, then "Income must be greater than or equal to zero" will be printed and nothing will return. To be honest I am having trouble figuring out exactly what you are trying to do, but you probably need to return something after printing.

Comment: I am trying to print the results of the tax function and percent of income function in the main function in the format of

main(filing status, income)
Tax: .....
Percent of Income:.....

Comment: Then just change the returns to prints.